# Browser Sends Two Cookies - PHP's Session Handler Reads Wrong One

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies

For a period of time cookies were set on a single site with different values for the `domain`.  This resulted in some people having cookies with the same name set for both `.www.domain.com` and `.domain.com`.  The site is intended to be accessed as `www.domain.com`.  This is accomplished with .htaccess rules.

The code will use `.domain.com`. now for the `session.cookie_domain` going forward.

The issue I am having is that when both cookies exist the browser sends both (both are valid).  I see this is so in the headers and also when dumping out `apache_request_headers()`, however, when I dump out `$_COOKIE` I see just one of them.

```
["Cookie"]=>
  string(74) "foobar=hkej4qdnq5kismiq3kl07qv6k2; foobar=ocvn7anlu2f2k2l37nl9ou3c21"
```

And then...

```
array(1) { ["foobar"]=> string(26) "hkej4qdnq5kismiq3kl07qv6k2" }
```

My session interface `read($id)` method is checking the old cookie and not the one we set on login.

What is the best way to address this?  I am thinking I could just change the session name/identifier and start fresh.  Or maybe evaluate the Apache headers in my `read` implementation.  I have not found much that is relevant in searching the web, just a bunch of fluff from w3schools polluting the results,  so I thought this might be a good one to post here.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by changing the session name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the session name.

PHP allows you to access the variable `$_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]` and parse it yourself. This allows you to access both values, of the cookie, but you can still not tell apart the correct and the wrong cookie.

Unless those cookies contain really valuable data, I would not care about the old values and just start new.

Comment: Makes sense.  I had done this once but believe I still had a conditional in there that determined the domain to use with the cookie... intending to allow app to work with different approaches for www/non www prefix.  Backed that out so I should have a consistent domain setting going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the session name from PHPSESSID to SITESESSID or something else of your choice. This will make sure that your application ignores the old cookie all together. If the lifetime of your session is 0, then its a SESSION Cookie(Gets deleted when the browser is closed), in such case you can change the session name back to PHPSESSID after a few days or a month of implementation since you will be sure that no one has the old cookie.

BTW: The browser isn't sending two cookies. It's just your old session cookie still alive.

Comment: The request headers show both cookies are being sent.  Not sure I get the distinction you are making.  Have reached same conclusion though changing session name (and not recreating the root cause of dupe cookies) is the best solution.

Comment: You are right.. The browser will send two cookies.. What I meant was the server will send only one cookie at session creation... I confused browser with server lol